# Converting aggregate of total length of ListField value from all rows based on condition on another column in django

Tags: python, django, mongodb, django-queryset

I am using this code to find number of values in list field `imported_leads` based on condition on other column message_from by iterating over for loop.

```
    om_leads = OttMessage.objects.filter(message_from=message_from, imported_leads__0__exists=True)

    total_leads_count = 0

    for ol in om_leads:
        total_leads_count+=len(ol.imported_leads)

    print total_leads_count
```

Is there any way to find `total_leads_count` variable value efficiently? I am trying to use aggregate to find total_leads_count but don't know how to use it on ListField in django. Can anybody help me or give some direction.
 Thanks

Comment: Is this a `ListField`, or an `ArrayField`?

Comment: Django mongodb `ListField`